# Por que isto funciona? ponteiroa = (struct a *)&b;

Tags: c, struct, cast

```
struct a {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct b {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct a *ponteiroa;
struct b b;

b.b = 20;

ponteiroa = &b; //Isto não dá certo
ponteiroa = (struct a *)&b;
```

Por que isto `(struct a *)&b` dá certo? Por que o programa consegue, mesmo sendo estruturas diferentes, fazer a atribuição?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 10):

Eu poderia responder que é porque C é uma linguagem fracamente tipada, ela tenta fazer funcionar, mesmo que dê resultados inesperados. Mas como ela é de tipagem estática não aceita o tipo ser diferente, então se você está dizendo que o tipo é adequado o compilador aceita. E você fez isso quando indicou uma coerção com o operador de *cast* `(struct a *)`, portanto para todos efeitos está jogando uma estrutura para outra e é problema seu se o resultado será bom ou não. Você fez compilar, mas nada garante que estará certo. No caso vemos que até dará porque apesar de nomes diferentes a estrutura é a mesma.

Mas nesse caso em específico é até mais simples porque ambos são ponteiros e todos ponteiros são compatíveis (todos são um simples endereço de memória e ele é universal), o objeto que eles apontam é que podem não ser, nesse caso é também. Em todo caso você precisa indicar para o compilador que quer fazer isso mesmo, porque ele acha que pode dar um problema e impede, a não ser que você seja explícito, como foi através do *cast*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).